# How do I create a new dataframe column based on certain conditons as it gives me a TypeError: where() takes from 1 to 3 pos args but 4 were given?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a new dataframe using pandas using a few values.
This is how I have created a dataframe:

```
dataframe['ON/OFF'] = np.where((dataframe['Height'] == median_height) & (
                dataframe['State Hash'] == most_common_state_hash) & (dataframe['File Name']!= name_of_file), 1, 0, -1)
```

The expected dataframe that I intend to get is something like

```
Cards                   Height                    State Hash   Online/Offline
                                                      
0    1615427359331  ...         1945  3NK38AjJUMDcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...     1
0    1615427359331  ...         1952  3NK38AjJUMvcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...     1
0    1615427359331  ...         1958  3NK38AjJUMDhEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...     0
0    1615427359331  ...         1952  3NK38AjJUMDcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT...     0
0    1615427359331  ...         1957  3NK38AjJUMhDcEkPVaTWKsMcccUWXywgpMRseaNNPz6gyhT..    -1
```

but instead I got a TypeError:

```
dataframe['State Hash'] == most_common_state_hash) & (dataframe['File Name']!= name_of_file), 1, 0, -1)
 File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in where
TypeError: where() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I understood the nature of the error as it says that the arguments should be more than 3. In that case How do I fulfill this condition? Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
dataframe['ON/OFF'] = np.select([(dataframe['Height'] == median_height),
                                 (dataframe['State Hash'] == most_common_state_hash),
                                 (dataframe['File Name']!= name_of_file)], 
                                 [1, 0, -1])
```